# Laravel Docker "Unable to create a directory at /var/www/storage/app/documents"

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile, laravel-9

I use Laravel 9 with Docker if I want to upload images like this:

```
$document["file_object"]->store('documents')
```

I get the following error: Unable to create a directory at /var/www/storage/app/documents
It looks like it ist some kind of Docker permission error.

I use the local Filesystems Disk because none of my files should be public.
If I change the `'root' => storage_path('app')` to `'root' => storage_path('')` inside the filesystems config I don't get any error but the files are saved in here: /storage/documents but they should be in /storage/app/documents.

I think I need to modify some docker user permission, but im unsure how as I'm not the one who made the config an my docker skills are limited.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && docker-php-ext-enable opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql -j$(nproc) gd \
    && apt-get autoclean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 

RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis

# Update apache conf to point to application public directory
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# Update uploads config
RUN echo "file_uploads = On\n" \
    "memory_limit = 1024M\n" \
    "upload_max_filesize = 512M\n" \
    "post_max_size = 512M\n" \
    "max_execution_time = 1200\n" \
    > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini

# Enable headers module
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers 
ADD . /var/www
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
# https://waihein.medium.com/configuring-redis-on-docker-in-laravel-58a39556ff97
# https://medium.com/@chewysalmon/laravel-docker-development-setup-an-updated-guide-72842dfe8bdf
# https://shouts.dev/articles/dockerize-a-laravel-app-with-apache-mariadb

# FIRST Start:
# 1. Run ON WINDOWS: docker run --rm -v ${pwd}:/app composer install 
# or on UNIX: docker run --rm -v “$(pwd)”:/app composer install
# 2. Run: npm run setup 
# npm run setup is doing: "docker-compose up -d --build && docker-compose exec app php artisan key:generate && docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate:fresh --seed && npm install && npm run dev"


# NORMAL Start: npm start
# npm start is doing: "docker-compose up -d && npm install && npm run dev"


# To stop: docker-compose down
version: '3.8'
services:
  # Application & web server
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    working_dir: /var/www
    container_name: immo-app
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - "database"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - immonet
  # Database
  database:
    image: 'mariadb:latest'
    container_name: immo-database
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - immonet
  # Database management
  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin:5.1
    container_name: immo-phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - PMA_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - PMA_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - PMA_PORT=${DB_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    networks:
      - immonet
  # Redis
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: immo-redis
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis:/data
    expose:
      - 6379
    networks:
      - immonet

volumes:
  dbdata:


networks:
  immonet:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `www-data` as the owner and group of your `/var/www` folder. It should be your nomal user (possibly WSL user?). If the docker container does not work without `www-data`, then you need to refactor it a bit, but the issue is arround the permissions.

Just try having your normal user as the owner and group of `/var/www`